# How do I pass my XML Dialog.FileName to my StreamReader for deserialization?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, serialization

So currently in my WPF project, I have the user browse for an XML file and then I want to deserialize that XML file and display the data in a DataGrid.

I'm sure my deserialize function works. However, I currently have it set to deserialize only one XML file as shown below:

```
public static void DeSerializationXML()
    {
        XmlRootAttribute xRoot = new XmlRootAttribute();
        xRoot.ElementName = "lot_information";
        xRoot.IsNullable = false;
        // Create an instance of analytes class.
        LotInformation[] lotinfo;
        // Create an instance of stream writer.
        TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\~\lot-123456.xml");
        // Create and instance of XmlSerializer class.
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LotInformation[]), xRoot);
        // DeSerialize from the StreamReader
        lotinfo = (LotInformation[])xmlSerializer.Deserialize(txtReader);
        // Close the stream reader
        txtReader.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();   
    }
```

In another function, I have the following that allows the user to browse for a file and upload it:

```
private void ChangeLotFilePath()
    {
        OpenFileDialog Dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        Dialog.Filter = "XML files (*.xml)|*.xml";
        Dialog.ShowDialog();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Dialog.FileName))
        {
            LotFileCreationDirectory = Dialog.FileName.ToString();
        }

        DeSerializationXML();
    }
```

Now I am wondering, how do I pass Dialog.FileName.ToString() to the StreamReader so that it will recognize the file path selected by the user?

Comment: Just nitpicking: *Dialog.FileName* is already a string, no need to call the *ToString()* method there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you take in the path as a parameter?

```
public static void DeSerializationXML(string path)
{
     ...
     TextReader txtReader = new StreamReader(path);
}

private void ChangeLotFilePath()
{
    using (var dialog = new OpenFileDialog()) {
        dialog.Filter = "XML files (*.xml) | *.xml";

        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            DeserializationXML(dialog.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: NP. I edited my answer with a better syntax and now handles disposing for you. If this works for you please accept as answer.

Comment: I will, there was a 2 minute restriction on when I can accept an answer. Thanks for the edit for clarity. Btw, are there any restrictions on what I can pass as a parameter from on function to another? Just for future note.